# How to create delivery order for confirmed Manufacturing Orders in openerp in custom module?

Tags: odoo

How to create delivery order for confirmed Manufacturing Orders in openerp in custom module?Exactly like creating delivery order for confirmed sale/purchase order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When confirming the sale order a delivery order will be created. When confirming purchase order, a incoming shipment is created.Like that when confirming manufacturing order, an internal move is created.

Comment: @OmaL. How can we create a custom field (say x_deliverydate) in delivery order which gets its value(already there) from sales order.? Thanks in adance

Comment: you need to customise it. check the sale_stock module